# What are the available API's supported for Viva Engage to get the details on who is liking and commenting on the posts and poll

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, yammer

What are the available API's supported for Viva Engage to get the details on who is liking and commenting on the posts and poll asked on the Viva Engage. There are api to manage the communities like creating and deleteing the community but my ask is on getting information on how to get the details of individuals who are liking and commenting on the posts.

I tried exploring on the communities

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/engagement-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta ...why asking here then? (voting to close)

Comment: @DiegoD my question is diff than the link what you have shared

Answer (score 0):

The whole API for Viva Engage is still in preview and supports only creating a community and retrieving basic details like name and description.

```
POST /beta/employeeExperience/communities
GET /beta/employeeExperience/communities/{communityId}
```

No endpoints to get details.